# android java.lang.NullPointerException on Sensor

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sensors

I was playing around with the accelerometer sensor and see how it works, to do so i wanted to display the force of the phone movement in real time on a TextView.
But every time i press the btnStart button it gives me the java.lang.NullPointerException ERROR. But i really cannot see that error in my code, i suppose it happens when i declare the sensor but it doesnt make any sense since that is the propper way of declaring it.
code:

```
package com.example.accelerometermine;

import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener, OnClickListener{


private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Button btnSta, btnSto;
private TextView txt;
private boolean started = false;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnSta = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    btnSto = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
    txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    btnSta.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSto.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnSta.setEnabled(true);
    btnSto.setEnabled(false);
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (started == true) {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (started) {
        double x = event.values[0];
        double y = event.values[1];
        double z = event.values[2];

        double xa = Math.abs(x);
        double ya = Math.abs(y);
        double za = Math.abs(z);

        double force = xa + ya + za;

        txt.setText("0" + force);
    }
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.btnStart:
        btnSta.setEnabled(false);
        btnSto.setEnabled(true);
        started = true;
        Sensor accel = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accel, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        break;
    case R.id.btnStop:
        btnSta.setEnabled(true);
        btnSto.setEnabled(false);
        started = false;
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

}

in the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Start" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnStop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:text="Stop" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="89dp"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: Post the logcat error trace, and indicate for us which line of your source corresponds to the numbered line in the "caused by" mention of the null pointer.  While you are at it, identify the object of which you try to use a field or method on that line, and think about what sort of failures could have caused that object to still be null.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialise the sensorManager in the onCreate method, otherwise it will of course be null when you press the button, and using:

```
sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
```

will cause the NullPointerException you're experiencing.

Add something like this to your onCreate:

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have just declared variable for `SensorManager`. You forgot to initialize it. So initialize it on `onCreate()` method. Like,

```
 sensorManager = (SensorManager)this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
```